# Black screen with cursor after login in cinnamon when VGA monitor is plugged

Tags: 16.04, login, cinnamon, vga, mint

I have a problem with an Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS + Cinnamon installation and Linux Mint 18.1 + Cinnamon: black screens after login when an external VGA monitor plugged. These are the facts:

- *Sometimes* I power on the computer, login with my password and get a black screen.
- When this happens, the cursor is always visible anyway.
- In these cases, I am still able to Ctrl+Alt+F1 (though it takes roughly 30 seconds), kill lightdm or mdm and try again - I might or might not be successful after this step.
- When this happens, Ctrl-Alt-Backspace restarts X (though it takes roughly 30 seconds), briefly show the wallpaper and brings me to the login screen.
- When I start with runlevel 3, I still get a black screen and no opportunity to login.
- When this happens, Ctrl-Alt-Del reboots the system and shows the splash.
- When login in software rendering mode, I can login without problems.
- When booting in recovery mode and then normal boot I can login without problems, but a) in software rendering mode and b) without external VGA monitor.
- One thing that always ends up working is performing a hard shutdown on the computer (holding the power button) and then I'm usually able to login as normal.
- These problems don't happen with Unity on Ubuntu.
- When booting without the VGA screen, everything works fine.
- When plugging the VGA screen after login, the screen freezes.
- Using the commercial Intel drivers won't solve the issue.
- Using "mirror" didn't work.
- Changing the layout as suggested [in this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1012164) didn't work.
- Disabling desktop icons as suggested [in this thread](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=104578) didn't work.

Is there a systematic way to debug this issue and diagnose the problem? Can anyone point out what important information do I need to focus on to debug this issue? X logs, disabling the screensaver, perhaps other things?

```
jlcano@jlcano ~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
Release:    18.1
Codename:   serena
jlcano@jlcano ~ $ uname -a
Linux jlcano 4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 17:47:47 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
jlcano@jlcano ~ $ inxi -Fx
System:    Host: jlcano Kernel: 4.4.0-57-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: Cinnamon 3.2.7 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.1)
           Distro: Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
Machine:   System: TOSHIBA product: Satellite Pro A50-C v: PS56AE-07S013CE
           Mobo: TOSHIBA model: Satellite Pro A50-C v: Version A0
           Bios: TOSHIBA v: Version 6.10 date: 07/15/2015
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-5500U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 4096 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 9577
           clock speeds: max: 3000 MHz 1: 2899 MHz 2: 2899 MHz 3: 2899 MHz
           4: 2899 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.00hz, 1920x1080@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 256 bits)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Card-2 Intel Broadwell-U Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:03.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.4.0-57-generic
Network:   Card-1: Intel Ethernet Connection (3) I218-V
           driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k port: 3080 bus-ID: 00:19.0
           IF: enp0s25 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full
           mac: b8:6b:23:10:be:c6
           Card-2: Intel Wireless 7265 driver: iwlwifi bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: wlp2s0 state: down mac: 10:02:b5:1c:dc:2a
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (2.2% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: TOSHIBA_MQ01ABD1 size: 1000.2GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 622G used: 14G (3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 8.50GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda6
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 75.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 188 Uptime: 26 min Memory: 1103.9/7892.8MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.461) inxi: 2.2.35 
jlcano@jlcano ~ $ lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI [8086:1604] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1616] (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller [8086:160c] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller [8086:9cb1] (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 [8086:9cba] (rev 03)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-V [8086:15a3] (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [8086:9ca0] (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 [8086:9c9a] (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 [8086:9c94] (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller [8086:9ca6] (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9cc3] (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] [8086:9c83] (rev 03)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 61)
jlcano@jlcano ~ $ cat .xsession-errors 
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
/etc/mdm/Xsession: Beginning session setup...
localuser:jlcano being added to access control list
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
Window manager warning: Software rendering detected: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 256 bits)
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
Cjs-Message: JS LOG: About to start Cinnamon
Cjs-Message: JS LOG: ACTIVATING SOFTWARE RENDERING
St-Message: cogl npot texture sizes SUPPORTED
Cjs-Message: JS LOG: Cinnamon started at Tue Jan 10 2017 09:46:23 GMT+0100 (CET)
Cjs-Message: JS LOG: network applet: Cannot find connection for active (or connection cannot be read)
openGL version 3.3 detected (GL3 Cogl Driver)
MetaSyncRing disabled: couldn't find required GL extensions, or the minimum safe openGL version was not met
Cjs-Message: JS LOG: Invalid network device type, is 14
Cjs-Message: JS LOG: network applet: Found connection for active
Cjs-Message: JS LOG: Removing an access point that was never added
mintUpdate: no process found
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_window_move_resize: assertion '!window->override_redirect' failed
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_window_move_resize: assertion '!window->override_redirect' failed
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_window_move_resize: assertion '!window->override_redirect' failed
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_window_move_resize: assertion '!window->override_redirect' failed
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_window_move_resize: assertion '!window->override_redirect' failed
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_window_move_resize: assertion '!window->override_redirect' failed
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_window_move_resize: assertion '!window->override_redirect' failed
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_window_move_resize: assertion '!window->override_redirect' failed
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_window_move_resize: assertion '!window->override_redirect' failed
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
jlcano@jlcano ~ $ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for jlcano: 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:45 memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```

**Edit** the output of `sensors` after a whole day of usage:

```
jlcano@jlcano ~ $ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +85.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +49.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +49.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +49.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

**Edit** from OP deleted answer "setting only the external monitor and disabling the laptop screen did work."

Comment: Try binding `xrandr --auto` to shortcut, and press that shortcut after connecting the VGA monitor

Comment: Change display manager to `gdm`

Comment: Please [edit] the output of `sudo lshw -c video` into your question.  The outputs of `dmesg` as well as  `tail /var/log/syslog` after plugging in the external monitor might also be useful.

Comment: Please also [edit] in the output of  `lsb_release -a` and `uname -a`

Comment: If you need assistance with your Mint boot, you are in the wrong place. I'm happy to help you with 16.04.1, but Mint is off topic here so please [edit] out the Mint output and [edit] in the Ubuntu output to avoid having your question closed as off-topic. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: First, try installing the HWE kernel: `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04-edge`.  If you still have issues, try a newer Mesa version from <https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers>.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @QwertyChouskie, but I got other issues doing that and I had to rollback.

Comment: Which one caused the issues, the newer kernel, or the PPA?

Comment: The newer kernel. I got `flip_done timed out` messages on boot and nothing else.

Comment: @astrojuanlu You may wish to follow [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1637347)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your Sensors output:

```
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 75.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
```

If this information is accurate I would say your CPU is overheating and downclocking in an attempt to preserve itself resulting in the delays you are experiencing getting to a terminal and restarting X. To the best of my knowledge the **Broadwell-U series was not designed to run at these temperatures** and might be damaged due to the excessive heat. The root cause might be lack of fan rotation causing inadequate cooling.

Without having the hardware in question I cannot determine whether your provided sensor output is accurate. However, if it is, it's **a cause for immediate concern** and **should be addressed without delay.**

Since the Broadwell-U series has integrated graphics, excessive heat leading to malfunction may be the cause of the graphics issues you are experiencing.

Comment: I've attached the output of `sensors` after a whole day of usage to my answer too. I'm not sure if this is a root cause though, perhaps something is happening that is driving the CPU crazy and so the increase in temperature?

Comment: anyway, this is not normal. try changing your thermal paste.

Comment: I'm relieved to see the temps are lower now, in order to see temps even as high as you show currently I would expect the system to be under a heavy load. (It's not how long you use it, it's how hard you use it that leads to increased temps). Be that as it may, @RinaldoJonathan makes a valid point. Whether this is the root cause of your posted issue is irrelevant if your CPU gets so hot the die cracks. Please [edit] your responses to my comments below your question into it from Ubuntu and I'll take another look, but your first priority should be your cooling system.